# Boost converter with no semiconductors or integrated circuits?

Tags: voltage, boost

Is there a way to create a boost circuit with only these components (no semiconductors or integrated circuits)?

- Any manipulation of wires (inductors count)
- Motors
- Mechanical switches
- Relays
- Resistors
- Potentiometers
- Capacitors

This means no transistors or diodes.   Is this possible?

Note: the second part to my original question is now [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342220/will-a-voltage-step-up-circuit-increase-the-power-output-of-a-motor).

Comment: As regards the question look at http://radioremembered.org/vpwrsup.htm  Some of us 'old school' will remember the vibrator power supplies

Comment: Since the relays may only be useful in sub-kilohertz switching due to bounce, and required passive component (Cs and Ls) sizes scale up with decreased switching frequency, you're looking at some gnarly components for a standard boost converter.  But it should be possible.  The tough part will be closed-loop control sans semiconductors.

Comment: 1. The "conservation of energy" comment is distracting and unnecessary. 2. Your question should begin with the design constraints of the competition to make it clear that this is not an X/Y problem. 3. A link to the full competition rules would help people to give more useful answers.

Comment: "a propeller levitated vehicle is supposed to lift as much mass as possible. The rules limit battery voltage to 9v" - choose motors that produce the most lift when powered directly from the battery. Any extra circuit attempting to boost voltage will just waste power.

Comment: Right, now we know the real constraints! In which case the boost conversion is not going to help you because the limiting factor is the internal resistance of the battery. Your best bet is to get an optimal matching of motor power to propellor speed, which is more of a mechanical engineering problem.

Comment: Power from battery at 9v, directly into motor and prop with pitch and kv chosen to use the 9v to run at a speed which draws a large current from your battery. All a boost converter does is add weight, waste power, and change the motor effective kv.

Comment: The XY problem is strong with this one!

Comment: Pretty sure the prius does not use a boost converter. If it does, that design choice was probably forced upon them by some ridiculous set of circumstances, or there is more to the story or something.

Comment: The problem you will have, assuming the motor can handle the voltage, is the parts needed to boost the voltage will add considerable weight. Doubling the voltage even if you double the speed of the motors, will not double the lift. Your power to weight ratio may actually be worse than you started. But play away...

Comment: Ok, I gather that my assumption that I can step up the battery to a higher voltage to force a motor to draw more current from the battery and thus output more power (in the form of either increased force or speed) was wrong.   I am assuming that a motor is comparable to a resistor, and a higher voltage difference across it would increase the power dissipation (I assumed that this power would translate to motor power, as it translates to heat in a resistor).   As the boost converter without semiconductors issue has already been solved, I will split this question into two.

Comment: Its not so much that, the motor will go much faster at twice the voltage, but the efficiency of the propeller will drop off as the speed increases.

Comment: As I think this part of my question has been adequately answered, the second part (which I still do not understand) has been moved to a different post.   See the hyperlink in the question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to skin this with what you have listed.

Rotary converters spring to mind, basically a DC motor coupled to a DC generator (Which is just another DC motor), WW2 technology, lots of the old aircraft radios used these.

You could also use a motor with a set of cams operating switches to build a flying cap doubler, or even do this with a relay wired as an astable (This will be kind of hard on the relay contacts).

The vibrator was a special case of an astable relay actually designed for this use case, with carefully chosen inductors you got zero current switching and surprisingly good contact life. They were popular as a source of HT for valve based car radios in the 50's.

Am I allowed to take some of the copper wire and oxidise it to get copper oxide? If so I can make a copper oxide rectifier which opens up some possibilities.

Find yourself an **OLD** book on electrical machines, ideally dating from about 1930, there will be examples of all kinds of cool semi mechanical ways to do the stuff we do with a few chips these days.

Answer (score 4):

If you can stand the continual buzzer noise, these work.. for a while...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLdD4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Though by your definition, the bridge rectifier would be cheating... as such a capacitive doubler may be more to your liking.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBvrw1.png)</sup>

Or a more classical inductive booster.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feLOY7.png)</sup>

All of these would be horribly noisy though, not just audibly, but EMI too. Relay life will also be short.

Comment: These designs looks so bad. But they are still the best given the constraints.

Comment: @HarrySvensson No kidding right...